# Hibernate 5.2 delete on cascade on my tables postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes that depend on each other. and I want to do a cascade delete. the problem I have the following error :

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fk5o18odcs53r4t69hbgf35haj3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

```java
public class Workspace {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Project> projects;


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }


    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Workspace workspace;

private String description;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at")
private Date createdAt;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;
```

The problem is that the tables created with my JPA dont define the cascade type in the delete rules.
Do I have to define the constraint types directly by sql? Can JPA Hibernate not define these constraints?

Comment: This is a pure JPA / Hibernate related question, Spring Boot shouldn't be involved here. Better to mention the Hibernate version being used.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa version 2.0.4

Comment: Which uses 5.2.17.Final under the covers https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: `the tables created with my JPA dont define the cascade type in the delete rules` : why would they? That cascade directive is for the JPA provider to process the individual deletes, not to pass to the database. To understand what is going on you look at the SQL invoked for your code that does the deleting ...

Comment: So these types of constraints must always be added by the sql ticket?

Comment: what "sql ticket"? Your JPA provider issues SQL to delete rows when you decide to delete objects ... POST what SQL is issued,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify mappedBy parameter for Workspace class OneToMany relation.

```
@OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "workspace") 
private List<Project> projects;
```

And after that you could delete workspace and all projects will be deleted as well.